# Issue on autoIncrementing a value using findOneAndUpdate in MongoDB/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Well, I am trying to do autoincrement in node.

So I have a simple function that I found here [How to add auto increment to existing collection in mongodb/node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302487/how-to-add-auto-increment-to-existing-collection-in-mongodb-node-js)

```
    // Increment DB Value
exports.getNextSequenceValue = async function (sequenceName) {
    try {
        const seqNum = await db.collection('counters').findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: sequenceName
        }, {
            $inc: {
                seq: 1
            }
        }, {
            returnNewDocument: true
        });
        // Check if response has seqNum.seq exists
        console.log(seqNum.value.seq);
        if (seqNum && seqNum.value.seq) {
            return seqNum.value.seq
        } else {
            return 'what ever you want '
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

and my controller where i used it.

```
const user = new User({
    profile: {
      firstname: req.body.firstname,
      lastname: req.body.lastname,
      location: req.body.location,
      status: 1,
      avatar: "/uploads/avatars/defaultProfilePic.jpg"

    },
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    xid: core.getNextSequenceValue('userid') // ----HERE ITS FUNCTION-----

  });
  console.log(core.getNextSequenceValue('userid')) //---- [object Promise]X ---
  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  }, (err, existingUser) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (existingUser) {
      req.flash('errors', {
        msg: 'Account with that email address already exists.'
      });
      return res.redirect('/signup');
    }
    user.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });
  });
};
```

But now i get error.

```
ValidationError: User validation failed: xid: Cast to Number failed for value "Promise { <pending> }" at path "xid"
```

Have no idea how to fix it.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should be simply awating `seqNum` as `await seqNum;`. And then returning the `seq` field from it `return seqNum.seq;` Also console `seqNum` once to check if you're getting desired doc.

Comment: Ou yes it help thank you very much :) but i used instead solution from srinivas answer but with both solutions i am getting new same error. (i updated my question)

Comment: So You have solved your query problem right. But in your controller code if u see you need to do stuffs after you've gotten the value of `xid`. One way is to wrap all of it in a `core.getNextSequenceValue('userid').then(r=> ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your issue seems to be with `new : true` when you're using `findOneAndUpdate()`, it has to be `returnNewDocument: true` more over you need to do await on function which takes sometime to finish but not on the response of it. Remember to always wrap your async & await with try-catch block.

```
exports.getNextSequenceValue = async function (sequenceName) {
    try {
        const seqNum = await db.collection('counters').findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: sequenceName
        }, {
                $inc: {
                    seq: 1
                }
            },
            { returnNewDocument: true }
        );
        // Check if response has seqNum.seq exists
        console.log(seqNum.seq);
        if (seqNum && seqNum.seq) { return seqNum.seq } else {
            return 'what ever you want '
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much now it returning correct value. But i get new error (i updated my question). I am lost in this async world. Tried again putting "await" before function call in sign up controller but it doesnt help.

Comment: @aNOTHERacCoUNTxxx : at xid: core.getNextSequenceValue('userid') try to change to core.getNextSequenceValue('userid').then(someValue => return someValue).catch();

Comment: This would still not work because the `user.save()` is outside the scope of then.

Comment: @aNOTHERacCoUNTxxx : Can you please close this as original ask is about mongoDB issue of having new  and open a new with node js question tagged with async and await, I think you need to make changes to your code move schema to a different place rather-than with along side with handler and move your code to async-await's or change the calling structure if needed..

Comment: @srinivasy Thank for your time. Yes i will :)