# How to add an auto incrementing value in already existing collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 1,00,000 records in a collection.I want to update a new field serial number as (S_no) in my collection which should start from 1 and end at 100000.How can it be done?

Comment: Please checkout this Answer this will help you :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302487/how-to-add-auto-increment-to-existing-collection-in-mongodb-node-js

Also MongoDB does not have an inbuilt auto-increment functionality.

Comment: @Sunil : Are you still waiting for an answer or is it resolved ?

Comment: It is not resolved still also i tried the steps from above link but still didn't get the result @srinivasy

Comment: @Sunil : So do you want 1 goes to document which is first created & 100000 goes to last created document like that or is that ok to be randomly inserted ?

Comment: Exactly!! 1 should go to first and 100000 should go to last document.